# Unit test class with one public and multiple private methods

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, moq

I'm having a little trouble understanding how to approach the following in order to unit test the class.

The object under test is an object that consists out of 1 public method, one that accepts a list of objects of type A and returns an object B (which is a binary stream).
Due to the nature of the resulting binary stream, which gets large, it is not a nice comparison for the test output.
The stream is built using several private instance helper methods.

```
class Foo
{
    private BinaryStream mBinaryStream;
    public Foo() {}
    public BinaryStream Bar(List<Object> objects) {
        // perform magic to build and return the binary stream;
        // using several private instance helper methods.
        Magic(objects);
        MoreMagic(objects);
    }
    private void Magic(List<Object> objects) { /* work on mBinaryStream */ }
    private void MoreMagic(List<Object> objects) { /* work on mBinaryStream */ }
};
```

Now I know that I need to test the behaviour of the class, thus the Bar method.
However, it's undoable (both space and time wise) to do compare the output of the method with a predefined result.
The number of variations is just too large (and they are corner cases).

One option to go for is to refactor these private helper methods into (a) separate class(es) that can be unit tested. The binary stream can then be chopped into smaller better testable chunks, but also here goes that a lot of cases need to be handled and comparing the binary result will defy the quick time of a unit test. It an option I'd rather not go for.

Another option is to create an interface that defines all these private methods in order to verify (using mocking) if these methods were called or not. This means however that these methods must have public visibility, which is also not nice. And verifying method invocations might be just enough to test for.

Yet another option is to inherit from the class (making the privates protected) and try to test this way.

I have read most of the topics around such issue, but they seem to handle good testable results. This is different than from this challenge.

How would you unit test such class?

Comment: So, you have class with unknown behavior? You call `Bar` method and you don't know what will be returned by this method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you are on top of how to deal with the private methods. Testing the stream for the correct output. Personally I'd use a very limited set of input data, and simply exercise the code in the unit test.

All the potential scenarios I'd treat as an integration test.

So have a file (say xml) with input and expected output. Run through it, call the method with the input and compare actual output with expected, report differences. So you could do this as part of checkin, or before deploy to UAT or some such.

Comment: This is the solution that was used eventually

Comment: It would be nice if we could afford a better solution, but sometimes brute force and sweat is the most practical option. :(

Answer (score 1):

Your first option (extract out the functionality into separate classes) is really the "correct" choice from a SOLID perspective.  One of the main points of unit testing things (and TDD by extension) is to promote the creation of small, single responsibility classes.  So, that is my primary recommendation.

That said, since you're rather against that solution, if what you're wanting to do is verify that certain things are called, and that they are called in a certain order, then you can leverage Moq's functionality.

First, have BinaryStream be an injected item that can be mocked.  Then setup the various calls that will be made against that mock, and then do a `mockStream.VerifyAll()` call on it - this verifies that everything that you setup for that mock was called.

Additionally, you can also setup a mock to do a callback.  What you can do with this is setup an empty string collection in your test.  Then, in the callback of the mock setup, add a string identifying the name of that function called to the collection.  Then after the test is completed, compare that list to a pre-populated list containing the calls that you expect to have been made, in the correct order, and do an EqualTo Assert.  Something like this:

```
public void MyTest()
{
    var expectedList = new List<string> { "SomeFunction", "AnotherFunction", ... };
    var actualList = new List<string>();
    mockStream.Setup(x => x.SomeFunction()).Callback(actualList.Add("SomeFunction"));
    ...
    systemUnderTest.Bar(...);
    Assert.That(actualList, Is.EqualTo(expectedList));
    mockStream.VerifyAll();
}
```

Comment: But that forces to make that inner classes public - to make class testable. Is this acceptable?

Comment: @VikciaR 1) In this question there are no inner classes, and 2) I don't see how doing Moq callbacks makes inner classes public.  Or are you referring to my recommendation to split out the functionality into other classes?  If so, you can make them internal classes and just do a `MakeInternalsVisibleTo` attribute to only allow those classes to be viewable from your test library.

Comment: @Gjeltema: yes, I think what to do next. Like in this question, I expose some API - it is short, but behind is large functionality. If I will test that public interface, I will get gazillions of tests, which will be pretty hard to understand and maintain. If I move functionality to private interfaces/classes and make them public to make them testable - I will show to user inner mechanics and user (of course) will use them directly.

Comment: @Gjeltema: Then I will be forced to maintain that inner interfaces, which doesn't planned to be public. If I make these classes internal, then my DependencyInjection will be also tricked how to compose object...

Comment: @VikciaR Sounds like something you should ask as a separate question, instead of in comments.  What you're asking about is a bit more involved than what the above questioner asked, and I don't think I could do a proper answer in this limited space.

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to test private methods - they don't exist from consumer point of view. Consider them as named code regions which are there just to make your `Bar` method more readable. You always can refactor `Bar` method - extract other private methods, rename them, or even move back to `Bar`. That is implementation details, which do not affect class behavior. And class behavior is exactly what you should test.

So, what is behavior of your class? What are consumer expectations from your class? That is what you should define and write down in your tests (ideally just before you make them pass). Start from trivial situations. What if list of objects is empty? Define behavior, write test. What if list contains single object? If behavior of your class is very complex, then probably your class doing too many things. Try to simplify it and move some 'magic' to dependencies.

Comment: For me that point "move magic to dependencies" is unclear. Dependencies will be public - to be testable. In that way we open "implementation details, which should be hidden and doesn't exist from consumer point of view".