# How to avoid re-testing the same behavior with unit test in javascript? (methods visibility and unit test)

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, tdd

TDD Principle :

- Test behavior of public method for class. Private method get tested anyway cause public method called them. Don't test private method.
- Test expected behavior by the customer like Sergey Berezovskiy explain [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18598865/4625305)

Fair enough, this seem really good and simple. However, in the bellowing example, this principle cause re-testing the same thing more then once. This lead into having the second and third biggest mistake listed in this [top 5 TDD mistakes article.](http://www.telerik.com/blogs/top-5-tdd-mistakes) Which are "too much many setup" and "too many assertion".

Example:

```
MyClass = function ()
{
    var self = this;    
    self.Tasks = [];
    self.IsExpanded = false;
    var _IsLoaded = false; 

    //Private
    function _LoadTasks()
    {
        //api call to load task
        _SortTasks();
    };

    //Private    
    function _SortTasks(tasks)
    {
        //Sort self.Tasks array
    };

    //Public    
    self.Method3 = function ()
    {
        //Do stuff
        if (HasDoneSomething)
        {
            _SortTasks();
        }
    };

    //Public    
    self.Method2 = function (param)
    {
        //Do stuff
        _SortTasks();
    }

    //Public    
    self.Method1 = function ()
    {
        if (self.IsExpanded)
            _Collapse();
        else
            _Expand();
    };

    //Private    
    function _Expand()
    {
        if (!_IsLoaded)
        {
            _LoadTasks();
        }
        self.IsExpanded = true;
    };

    //Private    
    function _Collapse()
    {
        self.IsExpanded = false;
    };
}
```

In the example above, three public methods may impact order of tasks. This lead into having an assertion on the sort order that repeat itself in multiple test.

```
test("Some test 2", 2, function ()
{
    //Setup 
    var myClass = Builder.Build();

    //Action
    myClass.Method2(SomeParam);

    //Assertion
    ok( jobWasDoneProperly, "Task should now be started");
    ok( resuledSortIsGood, "Task started was moved after already started tasks and before unstarted ones");
});

test("Some test 3", 3, function ()
{
    //Setup 
    var myClass = Builder.Build();

    //Action
    myClass.Method3();

    //Assertion
    ok( taskLoadedCorrectly, "Tasks are loaded");
    ok( taskAreExpanded, "Tasks are expanded");
    ok( resuledSortIsGood, "Task started was moved after already started tasks and before unstarted ones");
});
```

Having assertion on the sort required some setup to verify the resulted sort. Thus causing mistake of having to much setup as mentioned earlier.

**Issue could be easily solved by** testing the "private" method "SortTasks". This way, I could only assert that "SortTask" is called with a spy instead of actually testing the resulted sort in test of "method1", "method2" and method3". This doesn't reduce assertion count, but it does reduce a lot the setup's length as less verification is required. However, this indicate that something smell in the code since it would go against TDD principle.

In c#, **one way around** would be to create a new class name "TaskList" that inherit of List. Implement a public sort method to it. Then use this class to hold "Tasks" in "MyClass" instead of an array. This way, we wouldn't break the rule "don't test private method" and everything would be nice. But I'm in javascript and my array is actually an Knockout [obserbaleArrays,](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html) I checked briefly if is it possible to inherit of a array in javascript. It seemed possible but I'm not interested in going there because it didn't seem built in at all and too much complicated. I don't want to maintain such a thing.

**What is the proper way to test the sort in this issue while respecting the "Don't test private method" rule?**

Answer (score -1):

First of all in TDD the test amount compared to your amount of code is not sufficient.
for this amount of code you probably would get 200+ lines of tests.

You said correctly that in C# you would inherit from list, and than you would probably inject it via constructor. you could do it with a spy easily.

You should test the outcome of the whole SUT , so if your sut is doing something , and it sorts stuff to implement it , you should not test the sorting - or passing an spy to see what happens.

Also you could implement easily a "private" function

```
MyClass = function(){
 _function privateFunc(){}
}
```

Now you cannot access it from outside

Also if you new to JS , I suggest you try out jasmine for testing , it goes very well for C# developers

Comment: Ok, I will have a look on how to make my function private for real in another topic. Thanks, will try your solution to it.  I already use QUnit to test and Sinon to spy, stub and mock thing. So far, it do work. Like I said, if I left my sort method public, i can test the sort alone and test that the sort is called. This way I test the whole SUT. But in doing so, I by bass by pass sort's private visibility.

Comment: Also about the 200lines+ of test codes, this is a shrinked version of tests just to explain what I mean. Your answer made me realize my question wasn't straightforward, so I edited my question to clarify. It should be clear now and you should be able to update your answer accordingly.